# The term "fairly thick skin" is a phrasal verb?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am Brazilian and I found a strange phrase:

Fonte [Are questions about undocumented functions deprecated on Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2199/are-questions-about-undocumented-functions-deprecated-on-mathematica-se?cb=1#comment9560_2200)

> Not offense taken. I have a **fairly thick skin**. I have revised my answer to give my opinion how to make such questions acceptable. Further, I do not always disapprove of your questions. I have up-voted quite a few of them.

The term "fairly thick skin" is a phrasal verb? Here in Brazil this does not mean anything normal for this context ...

Comment: It makes sense in portuguese too. It would be the same as "casca grossa".

Comment: "Fairly thick skin" is a _noun phrase_. It's not a verb of any kind.

Comment: A suggestion: the next time you encounter a phrase in English that you don't understand, consult an English language dictionary. They are not hard to find. The phrase _"thick skin"_ is treated in at least a dozen of them. I'd still like to know why you thought this one could be a verb, though. Do you know what a "verb" is in English?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phrase [*thick skinned*](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning%20of%20thick%20skin) is an idiomatic adjective that means you are able to withstand a lot of criticism, the idea being that you don't get hurt easily.

When someone says they have "a fairly thick skin" on a discussion board, that means their ego doesn't get bruised easily and their feelings are not usually hurt. It's figurative language.